# Search wikipedia article and retrieve description from xml via PHP

Tags: php, xml, wikipedia

I am trying to retrieve the content of searched wikipedia article content to my page. Here is my `$url` [Pink Floyd](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&redirects&titles=Pink_Floyd) and my code -

```
$curl = curl_init(); 
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( "Cache-Control: max-age=0",
                                                         "Connection: keep-alive",
                                                         "Keep-Alive: 300",
                                                         "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8",
                                                         "Accept-Language: $wikibox_options[language]",
                                                         "Pragma: " ) );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, WIKIBOX_AGENT );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate' );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120 );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120 );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5 );
            if ( $post ) {
                curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
                curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $post_content ) );
            }
            $result = curl_exec( $curl ); 
            curl_close( $curl );
```

But `$result` print nothing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this instead

```
<?php 
$result = file_get_contents('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&redirects&titles=Pink_Floyd');
 echo $result;
?>
```